# Find all nonnegative integers

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Determine all nonnegative integers $x$ and $y$ so that $$3^x + 7^y$$
>   is a perfect
>   square and $y$ is even.

Without trial-and-error of course.

$$3^x + 7^y = a^2$$ For some integer $a$.

$$\implies a = \sqrt{3^x + 7^y}$$

But is there really a way?

Comment: If y is even, you can rewrite it as $3^x=(a+7^{.5y})(a-7^{.5y})$ as well. I don't think both terms can be divisible by 3. So it only works if one of the terms is 1.

Comment: There are obvious solutions when $x=0$ and $y=0$. If $x,y >0$, with some computation you can get $3^{y-x-1} \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, but I don't know if that will help much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing $y = 2z$ we have $3^x = (a + 7^z)(a - 7^z )$.  Now $a + 7^x$ and $a - 7^x$ must be two powers of $3$, say $a + 7^x = 3^d$, $a - 7^x = 3^e$.
But $3^d - 3^e = 2 \times 7^x \equiv 2 \mod 3$ so we must have $e = 0$.  Then
$a = 1 + 7^x$, and  $3^d = a + 7^x = 1 + 2 \times 7^x$.  One solution is $x = 0$, $d = 1$, corresponding to $3^1 + 7^0 = 2^2$.  Otherwise, note that $3^d \equiv
1 \mod 7$ iff $d$ is divisible by $6$, but if $d$ is divisible by $6$ then $3^d \equiv 1 \mod 4$ as well, so $(3^d - 1)/2$ is divisible by $2$ and can't be a power of $7$.  So there are no other solutions.

Comment: You can also show that if $d$ is even along with $y$, then $3^d+7^y \equiv 2\pmod 4$, which contradicts $a$ being even.

Comment: @Robert, Great Answer. But why must $a - 7^x = 3^d$? Why must it be a power of three? Did you do: let $x = r  + t$ then, $3^{r}3^{t} = (a + 7^z)(a - 7^z)$$? Also then, why do you search $\pmod{3}$?

Comment: If a product of integers is a power of $3$, then each is a power of $3$.